# Создание трех взаимосвязанных конструкторов с методами

Tags: javascript, конструктор

Итак, уважаемое сообщество. Ввиду того, что я очень слабо понимаю принципы ООП,у меня возник вопрос ибо в своем самообразовании я крепко сел на мель. 
У меня есть три конструктора. Первый конструктор (пусть он будет mainObj), имеет два свойства. Я это отобразил следующим образом.

```
function MainObj (width,height) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
}
```

Следующий конструктор firstObj, назовем его так, вмещает метод который создает из вышеуказанного конструктора обьект и принимает параметры width,height.

Параметры в свою очередь приходят из другого конструктора secondObj, содержащий метод, который с помощью prompt запрашивает у пользователя параметры width и height.
Вся цепочка должна запускаться вызовом secondObj.
Моя трудность заключаеться в том, что я практически не представляю себе реализацию сего, а именно, как связать в цепь три конструктора, когда вызов одного инициализирует вызов последующего. Помогите, будьте так любезны.

Answer (score 2):

```
function MainObj(w, h) {
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
}


function FirstObj() {
    // Зачем нам этот конструктор?
}

FirstObj.methodThatCreateObjectOfMainObjClass = function (w, h) {
    return new MainObj(w, h);
}

function SecondObj(w, h) {
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.instanceOfMainObj = FirstObj.methodThatCreateObjectOfMainObjClass(w, h);
}

console.log(new SecondObj(1, 2));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, попробую его осмыслить.

Comment: Могли бы дать пояснение, как можно присваивать свойства с помощью prompt? Точнее как интегрировать prompt в тело конструктора?

Comment: `let someVar = prompt("Some string");` prompt это обычная функция